# Hinge/Configurable Joint rotating even if constrained

Tags: unity, physics, joints

I already posted the question over on [Unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/hinge-configurable-joint-rotating-even-if-constrained.402765/), though, I have to say, this place often seems more professional and knowledgable, so here goes mirror post.

I have a **Cylinder** with a *Hinge* and a **Pole** that is attached to the *Hinge*. The *Hinge* axis is is set to `Y`, due to **Cylinder** being flipped for it to be rollable.
[image: Scene view.]

This is the order in `Hierarchy`:
[image: Hierarchy view.]
(I've given various attempts, hence the [descriptive name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfxf5.jpg).)

The rigidbodies — left one for **Cylinder**, the right one for **Pole**:
[image: Cylinder rigidbody.] [image: Pole rigidbody.]
As can be seen, the **Pole** is set to `Freeze Rotation on X`.

And, the *Hinge*:
[image: Hinge joint.]

Nothing overly special, also, as per [HingeJoint documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html), I had attempted to "Disable Preprocessing" to no avail.

The problem is that even though the **Pole** is set to not rotate around `X`, it still does. For instance here, when the **Cylinder** has rolled all the way to it's stopping point, the **Pole** slowly rotates:
[image: A locked yet rolling pole.]

Full video of the roll can be seen here: [gifv @ imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDg9t.jpg).

I have also attempted to recreate the *Hinge* with *Configurable Joint*, didn't help either.

How do I stop this rotation? I need the **Pole** to mimic the roller **Cylinder**, just excluding the `X` rotation.

Comment: I have hacked a partial solution and it appears that it doesn't actually solve my problem. Will create a new question regarding the faced issue. As for this question, I'll leave it open, as it may still be of use given that someone might need such a precise joint.